# obj-c: generate random number from within range excluding variable two

Tags: objective-c, cocos2d-iphone

I am generating a random number between 0 and topOfRange. I can exclude firstNumberToExclude with this code:

```
NSInteger aRandom;
while ((aRandom = arc4random()%topOfRange) == firstNumberToExclude);
```

how about if I had two numbers to exclude: firstNumberToExclude and secondNumberToExclude? This was my plan but doesnt seem to be proper:

```
NSInteger aRandom = arc4random()%topOfRange;
while (aRandom == firstNumberToExclude || aRandom == secondNumberToExclude)
    {
    aRandom = arc4random()%topOfRange;
    }
```

Comment: You are assigning aRandom as soon as the condition in the loop is true ... seems wrong, did you mean to do that ?

Comment: @driis it's not wrong, if `aRandom` equals one of the numbers to be excluded, then you need to generate a new random number and re-assign it to `aRandom`.

Comment: @driis: in the second example you mean? yeah, i'm trying to only re-assign aRandom if the condition is true and then when it reassigns to something, recheck it

Comment: Code looks ok. What's the problem? I would've used a do/while loop instead - it's a little cleaner.

Comment: How are you passing in the numbers to exclude? Is the number of those variable as well as their values?

Comment: @EricS: Based on your comment I rechecked all the code and found an error elsewhere (in the assignment of "secondNumberToExclude"). code works. craig's answer to use a method works nicer than mine. thanks all

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think your code would be cleaner, and easier to maintain, if you refactored this into a utility method:

```
+ (NSInteger)generateRandomExcluding:(NSArray *)exclude topOfRange:(NSInteger)topOfRange {
    NSInteger aRandom = arc4random_uniform(topOfRange);
    while ([exclude containsObject:[NSNumber numberWithInteger:aRandom]]) {
        aRandom = arc4random_uniform(topOfRange);
    }
    return aRandom;
}
```

Then you can call it like:

```
NSNumber *excludeOne = [NSNumber numberWithInt:5];
NSNumber *excludeTwo = [NSNumber numberWithInt:13];

NSInteger random = [MyClass generateRandomExcluding:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:excludeOne, excludeTwo, nil] topOfRange:100];
```

Comment: You should also use arc4random_uniform(upper_bound) to avoid modulo bias.

Comment: my code does work, error was elsewhere but this works too and is clean and useful. thanks @craig.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
NSInteger aRandom = arc4random()%topOfRange;
NSMutableArray *exludedNumbers = [NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects:
    [NSNumber numberWithInt: firstNumberToExclude],
    [NSNumber numberWithInt: secondNumberToExclude],
    nil];
BOOL flag = YES;
while (flag)
{
    flag = NO;
    for (NSNumber *numberToExclude in excludedNumbers)
    {
        if (numberToExclude.intValue == aRandom)
        {
            flag = YES;
            aRandom = arc4random()%topOfRange;
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

so you could dynamically add and remove numbers to exclude from array

Comment: this solution is simple. You could improve it as craig did by using -containsObject method, but the sense is the same.

Answer (score 0):

Came across this recently looking for the same solution.  I think the while loop is a very bad idea, with random numbers, you can't truly know how long it will take. So i took another stab at it and adapted other solutions.

Generate the random number taking into account the pool of excluded numbers, then check if the the number is greater than any of the excluded numbers and increment 1 for each one.

```
- (NSInteger) randomNumberExcluding:(NSArray <NSNumber *> *) excludedNumbers range:(NSRange) range
{
    NSPredicate *pred = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"integerValue >= %d AND integerValue =< %d", range.location, NSMaxRange(range)];
    NSSortDescriptor *sorter = [NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"integerValue" ascending:YES];
    excludedNumbers = [[excludedNumbers filteredArrayUsingPredicate:pred] sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:@[sorter]];
    NSInteger base = arc4random_uniform((uint32_t)(range.length - excludedNumbers.count + 1)) + (NSInteger)range.location;
    for (NSNumber *excludedNumber in excludedNumbers) {
        if (base >= excludedNumber.integerValue) {
            base++;
        }
    }
    return base;
}
```